# How can prometheus be used to measure latency on asynchronous calls?

Tags: asynchronous, histogram, prometheus, latency, summary

I am using Prometheus to instrument my scala code. It works fine with Counters for most of the app related metrics.

When it comes to measuring latency, I am not sure how to use Summaries or Histograms (or some other metric type) to measure the latency of asynchronous calls. 
`Timer.observeDuration` in a callback does not really do the trick since the Timer is reset multiple times before one aync call is completed.

What approach should I take to measure asynchronous latency using prometheus metrics?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass around the timer object from where you create it to where the call is finally complete, and only then call `observeDuration`.